# how to send custom value from sale.order.line to stock.move in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I have created two fields, one in ***sale.order.line*** and one in ***stock.move***. When the sale.order get's confirmed it creates stock.picking with product info in stock.move. I want to send my custom field value from sale.order.line to stock.move. How to do that?

To send value from sale.order to stock.picking I used the '''**action_confirm**''' function. I can get the '''**picking_ids**''' and crate a stock.move in there. But that will not be efficient.

Is there any existing function in odoo like '''**_prepare_stock_moves()**''' to create the move from sales order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How the Delivery orders are created from Sale Order in ODOO 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215960/how-the-delivery-orders-are-created-from-sale-order-in-odoo-10)

Comment: it's not duplicate, because in v10 we had a function named - _prepare_order_line_procurement() to add custom values to stock.move . Now this is not the case in v12 anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is still there in odoo v12 but in a different way.

> In 'sale.order.line' model write this -

```
@api.multi
def _prepare_procurement_values(self, group_id=False):
    res = super(YourModelName, self)._prepare_procurement_values(group_id)
    # I am assuming field name in both sale.order.line and in stock.move are same and called 'YourField'
    res.update({'YourField': self.YourField})
    return res
```

> While creating stock.picking or stock.move it impacts
>   procurement/stock.rule. So, you will have to add the values in
>   stock.rule too. For that inherit the stock.rule model. Like this -

```
class StockRuleInherit(models.Model):
_inherit = 'stock.rule'

    def _get_stock_move_values(self, product_id, product_qty, product_uom, location_id, name, origin, values, group_id):
        res = super(StockRuleInherit, self)._get_stock_move_values(product_id, product_qty, product_uom, location_id,
                                                           name, origin, values, group_id)
        res['YourField'] = values.get('YourField', False)
        return res
```

Now, when you will confirm the sale order, the remarks value from the order line will be also carried to stock.move with other values.

Comment: Hi @Tanzil Khan, is this the same format to implement moving a field from sale order to stock picking when a sale is confirmed?

Comment: Hi @Eric, did you find à solution to what you needed ?

Comment: Yes @Gabin , the format was the same as this. Having any issues or a clarification?